# Iteratively filter a Pivot Table in google App script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I had a code that was helping me save as pdf a list of invoices. I was doing that by iterating through the list of our clients and filtering the "invoice pivot" with the client id and then saving as pdf the resulting pivot table.

Since last week my flow is not working anymore. I did some testing and ultimately understood that what is not working is this function **updateFilteredPivot()**. The filter is only applied in the first run of the iteration when the pivot table has no filter active. Any idea on what could have changed and how to work around this issue?

```
function updateFilteredPivotTable(lastRow, filter, pivotTableSheetName) {
  var lastRow = lastRow
  var filter = filter.toString()
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var pivotTableSheetName = pivotTableSheetName
  var pivotTableSheetId = ss.getSheetByName(pivotTableSheetName).getSheetId();
  var fields = "sheets(properties.sheetId,data.rowData.values.pivotTable)";
  var sheets = Sheets.Spreadsheets.get(ss.getId(), {fields: fields}).sheets; 
  for (var i in sheets) {
    if (sheets[i].properties.sheetId == pivotTableSheetId) {
      var pivotTableParams = sheets[i].data[0].rowData[0].values[0].pivotTable;
      break;
    }
  }
  
  // Update source range:
  pivotTableParams.source.endRowIndex = lastRow  ; // improve get last row with data in column A
  pivotTableParams.criteria = { 26: {"visibleValues": [filter]}}; // set filter field column 26 equal to filter
  
  // Send back the updated params
  var request = {
    "updateCells": {
      "rows": {
        "values": [{
          "pivotTable": pivotTableParams
        }]
      },
      "start": {
        "sheetId": pivotTableSheetId
      },
      "fields": "pivotTable",     
    }
  };
  
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({'requests': [request]}, ss.getId());
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any error? If I understood correctly, it stops at the first Sheet, right? Would you mind sharing an example of it?

Comment: i don't get any error. Simply the iteration keeps going but printing the same pivot table over over. This script above does not update the pivot table anymore after the first iteration. I did some test and the arguments passed to the function are correct, but the update does not happen.
The final output i get is the same pdf times the number of iterations.